# Event handler of the button doesn't work as expected in java?

Tags: java, swing

```
package FRAME;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Frame;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class UseFrame8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Frame8 obj new Frame8("FRAMME");
    }

}

class Frame8 extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    String title;

    public Frame8(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        setTitle(title);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(600,600);
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        JButton btn1= new JButton("Click me");
        add(btn1);
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn1.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
        MyWindowAdapter obj2= new MyWindowAdapter();


    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? What is "expected"? Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site.

Comment: 1) Why use an AWT based `Frame`?   The Swing equivalent is `JFrame`. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). It looks like the source could be made an MCVE by removing `MyWindowAdapter obj2= new MyWindowAdapter();`. Given that listener is not added to the frame, the code line does not achieve anything anyway. 3) **Since the constructor sets the BG color to `CYAN`, even if the button is working, it will produce *no visual effect*.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Button works exactly how you set him up. You just don't see any difference by clicking on it, because your background is already Cyan.

in actionPerformed try this instead:

```
this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```